# Scala map and groupby a Map to another Map, with a smaller keyset

Tags: scala, dictionary

Lets say there is a Scala Map, eg:

```
val map:Map[String, List[String]= Map("Apple" -> List("Red", "Tasty"), "Orange" -> List("Sour", "Orange"),  "Banana" -> List("Yellow"), "Mango" -> List("Best", "Yellow", "Favorite"))
```

Now I want to convert it to the following map, which uses only the map._1.size as key instead, and groups values with same keys together.

```
Map(5 -> List("Best", "Yellow", "Favorite", "Red", "Tasty"), 6 -> List("Sour", "Orange", "Yellow"))
```

So how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
map.groupBy(_._1.length).map { case (length, m) =>
  length -> m.values.flatten
}
```

First you group by length, and you'll get a `Map[Int, Map[String, List[String]]]`.
Then you need to flatten those map values to get the final result. You keep the key (`length`).

Answer (score 2):

You just group by the size as you said and then process the resulting collections further.

F.ex:

`map.groupBy(_._1.size).mapValues(_.values).mapValues(_.flatten)`

edit: Insan-e:s answer is superior since it avoids one iteration through the collection, even if the ever-present Scala pattern matching makes it a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution could be:

```
scala> map.groupBy(_._1.size).map(x => (x._1,x._2.values.flatten))
res89: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Iterable[String]] = Map(5 -> List(Red, Tasty, Best, Yellow, Favorite), 6 -> List(Sour, Orange, Yellow))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val result = map.map {case (string,list) => list.map( x => (string.length,x) ) }.flatten.groupBy(_._1).map{ case (int,list) => (int,list.map(_._2)) }
```